# AVPlayer streaming 3m8u video not correct sizes

Tags: swift, avplayer

I want stream video on AVPlayer. Faced with video size problem. For example one video can display good

[video1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut4eK.png)

but another video displaying like this

[video2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXuOp.png)

i tryed to make some changes with AVPlayerLayer but it also have a problem, for example

```
 let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer.init(player: player)
        var bounds:CGRect = view.layer.bounds
        playerLayer.frame = view.bounds
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
```

but in this case some video "protrudes from the screen"

[video1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PHGF.png)

but another ok.

Do i need calculate size of video dynamicaly? Or how i can get correct video sizes?

Comment: Increase the size of the fframe like you did, but don't change `playerLayer.videoGravity` - let it remain with its default vaue, which is `resizeAspect`

Comment: @akjndklskver thanks for the comment. I have tried like you sad but without any result

Comment: In that case you need to give more details, because hundreds of apps are using AVPlayer, and nobody has problems you do, so there must be something specific about your app.